# With a Cisco RV082 router, can I forward to a specific port?

Tags: cisco, router, nat

I have Cisco RV082 8-port 10/100 VPN Router - Dual WAN.
Can I make it forward to a specific port? I can't find Port Redirection in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it - it's on the **UPnP page under the Setup section.**

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.